# HTML Email Template Edit without wysiwyg

Tags: email-template, administration, user-admin

I am trying to edit an email template, however for some reason when I am editing I keep seeing WYSIWYG, and I am not able to change this to code view.

Is there a way to deactivate this, and have the code view?

The HTML Email Content is text, if I copy html tags it will still display the HTML Tags

[image]

Comment: There is a "spirited" IDEA discussion here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrkwAAC (read the newest comments for some eye-openers) and a partial solution with Lightning Experience. Otherwise, you can use VF templates where you can enter HTML tags directly

Comment: Thats interesting, however my question goes more on the way of changing the editor to just plain HTML, something similar to Wordpress or Joomla funcitonality when you are writing a page or article. I am just not sure if I am missing something on the page or if it is the way this tempalte was created? There are some other templates that have HTML code that can be edited inline